# What is the rigorous definition for intrinsic property?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for a rigorous non-handwavey definition for intrinsic property in regards to regular surfaces. I’ve heard that any expression that can be written in terms of the 1st FF is an intrinsic property. For instance $3^{I_p(w)} + I_p(w)$ is an intrinsic property of a surface, where $I_p$ is the 1st FF at $p \in S$ and $w$ is a tangent vector. Is this correct?

Comment: Express the surface as a [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold). If you can define the property in terms of that manifold structure, then it is intrinsic. If you cannot, it was extrinsic.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, I do not know anything about differential geometry other than regular surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so what you wrote makes no sense to me. Are you trying to say that anything expressed in terms of the 1st FF is intrinsic. So $3^{I_p(w)}+I_p(w)$ for instance is an intrinsic property of $S$?

Comment: I expected as much, which is why I made a comment instead of an answer. Intrinsic means it is a property of the surface itself, and not how the surface is embedded in space. Thus the most fundamental way of defining it is as a property of the abstract definition of a surface (2D Riemannian manifold). The "first fundamental form" is the metric on the surface, so yes, anything defined by it is intrinsic. Topological properties are also intrinsic.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So $3^{I_p}+I_p$ is an intrinsic property, correct?

Comment: I guess so. You have to understand that I don't have your book sitting in front of me, and it had been decades since I've looked at "fundamental forms", so I do not immediately recognize and understand your notations. I had to check wikipedia to confirm which fundamental form corresponded to the metric.

Comment: Spencer: What you wrote down requires computing the exponential of a quadratic form; whereas the exponential of a linear map is well-defined (i.e., independent of basis), the exponential of a bilinear form is not. However, the main point is that some things, like Gaussian curvature, are *defined* a priori using an embedding of the surface (here, in terms of the second fundamental form as well as the first), but can be shown to be dependent *just* on the first fundamental form. Hence, this is an intrinsic notion (just dependent on the Riemannian metric), even though we "see" it extrinsically.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi Ted. Thank you for the comment, I understand things a bit better. But what do you mean the exponential of the 1st FF isn't well defined? The 1st FF maps the tangent plane of a regular surface to $\mathbb{R}$, And so the exponent map of a scalar is well-defined. All I ask is to avoid hand-wavey explanations. My original question is can any expression written in terms of the 1st FF be considered an intrinsic property?

Comment: The first fundamental form is a *bilinear form* on the tangent plane, not a linear map from the tangent plane to itself.  When you change parametrizations, the bilinear map changes by $P^\top AP$, whereas a linear map changes by $P^{-1}AP$. You can check from the definitions that $e^{P^{-1}AP} = P^{-1}e^AP$, and so the exponential of a linear map is a well-defined linear map. However, the algebra does not work out to tell you that $e^{P^\top AP} = P^\top e^AP$ (unless $P$ happens to be an orthogonal matrix), and so the exponential of a bilinear map is not well-defined.

Comment: To summarize (and note there was no handwaving), what you write down must be a well-defined thing, independent of parametrization, in order for it to be "intrinsic" and, indeed, meaningful. (The second fundamental form, albeit extrinsic, computes something that transforms correctly — again, as a bilinear form — when you change parametrizations.)